# JavaScript button to render a partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to break my problem down to the smallest possible example, so I've ended up with this:

I have a button in my html home page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1()">Render Partial View</button>
<div id="demo1">PartialViewGoesHere</div>
```

And in my custom js I have the function:

```
function myFunction1()
{
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "";
}
```

I'd like the innerHTML to become a partial view / html string, but I don't know how to get the partial view HTML in to the string ""

---

After this, I'll be trying to include variables to the button click but I just wondered if this method is even possible.

Comment: Why not just showing/hiding partial view which already rendered in the page? Take note that `@Html.Partial()` or `@Html.RenderPartial()` or even `@Html.[Render]Action` cannot be used in external JS file, you need to send the partial view as HTML string parameter to the external JS function.

Comment: I will try this, sounds simple enough and might do for what I need at the minute but I still feel there should be an easier way to render partial views dynamically.